# .NET JsonReaderWriterFactory read error

Tags: .net, json, serialization

I was trying to load a .json file and read it using "JsonReaderWriterFactory".
My code is the following:

```
string path = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/")) + "JsonData/file.json";
byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(buffer, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

System.Xml.Linq.XElement root = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(reader);
```

But when I call "System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(reader)" I get an exception "**unexpected character 'ï'**".
What's wrong?
Should I specify a particular encode?
Thank you.

Data I am trying to read  should be an array of objects composed in this way:

```
[
    {
        id: "ITEM_ID",
        label: "Item Label",
        url: "http://www.address.com",
        parameters: [
            "PARAM_1",
            "PARAM_2"
        ],
        filters: {
            logic: "or",
            filters: [
                { field: "fieldA", operator: "eq", value: 100 },
                {
                    logic: "and",
                    filters: [
                        { field: "fieldA", operator: "lt", value: 100 },
                        { field: "fieldB", operator: "eq", value: true }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {...}, 
    {...} 
]
```

Comment: Well what does the data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first I would suggest you to validate your Json Data at http://jsonlint.com/
It seems that your Json data is not well formatted.

The error is coming because you haven't wrapped your keys with `" "` marks.
So it has to be like these.

```
{
    "id": "ITEM_ID",
    "label": "Item Label"
}
```

Comment: No, I edited and validated the json as you suggested, but no luck, same error. I also tried your two lines json: the code generate the same error. I was wondering if something other is wrong in the reader declaration.

Comment: I gues I found the solution: the problem of "unexpected chaarcter" was due to the editor I used to create the file. Using Notepad to re-create json data file has solved the problem. By the way, thankyou for addressing me to the right direction.